# Show .load-overlay if href has valid URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show the user a loading screen when the click a link. So when they click a `a href` width valid URL, the `.load-overlay` will show.

```
    $('a,input[type=submit]').click(function(){
        var bad = this.href.lastIndexOf('#') >= 0 || this.href.indexOf('javascript') >= 0;
        if(bad) {
            return false;
        } else {
            if ($("a").hasClass("noload")) {
                return false;
            } else {
                $(".load-overlay").show();
            });
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
```

But some URLs on my site have a `target="_blank"` attribute to the `a href`, so that opens a new window. However on the website it will show the loading overlay and that's a bad thing because the page doesn't load.

As you can see in the code I added a few more lines:

```
    $('a,input[type=submit]').click(function(){
        var bad = this.href.lastIndexOf('#') >= 0 || this.href.indexOf('javascript') >= 0;
        if(bad) {
            return false;
        } else {
            if ($("a").hasClass("noload")) {// if the a href has the class .noload, do not display the loading overlay
                return false;
            } else {
                $(".load-overlay").show();
            });
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
```

but that doesn't work. Anyone got an idea to fix this?

Comment: `});` instead of `}` on the 10th line may be why it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this code with your code to solve the problem:

```js
$('a,input[type=submit]').not('[target=_blank], .noload').click(function(){
  var bad = this.href.lastIndexOf('#') >= 0 || this.href.indexOf('javascript') >= 0;
  if(!bad) {
    $(".load-overlay").show();
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});
```